# Listing groups by ID and name

Tags: java, javafx

I have this JavaFX code which is used for listing groups by ID and name:

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Listobject extends Application
{

    public class GroupConverter extends StringConverter<ListGroupsObj>
    {

        @Override
        public String toString(ListGroupsObj obj)
        {
            return obj.getGroupId() + " - " + obj.getGroupName();
        }

        @Override
        public ListGroupsObj fromString(String obj)
        {

            return ListGroupsObj.newInstance().groupName(obj);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        // Insert Some data
        ListGroupsObj ob = ListGroupsObj.newInstance().groupId(12).groupName("Group12");
        ListGroupsObj osb = ListGroupsObj.newInstance().groupId(13).groupName("Group13");
        ListGroupsObj oa = ListGroupsObj.newInstance().groupId(14).groupName("Group14");
        ListGroupsObj oz = ListGroupsObj.newInstance().groupId(15).groupName("Group15");

        final ComboBox<ListGroupsObj> listGroups = new ComboBox();

        listGroups.setConverter(new GroupConverter());
        listGroups.setButtonCell(new GroupListCell());
        listGroups.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ListGroupsObj>, ListCell<ListGroupsObj>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell<ListGroupsObj> call(ListView<ListGroupsObj> p)
            {
                return new GroupListCell();
            }
        });

        listGroups.setEditable(true);

        listGroups.getItems().addAll(ob, osb, oa, oz);
        listGroups.setValue(ob);

        // Display the selected Group
        listGroups.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ListGroupsObj>()
        {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ListGroupsObj> arg0, ListGroupsObj arg1, ListGroupsObj arg2)
            {
                if (arg2 != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Selected Group: " + arg2.getGroupId() + " - " + arg2.getGroupName());
                }
            }
        });

        final StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(listGroups);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 15;");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    class GroupListCell extends ListCell<ListGroupsObj>
    {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ListGroupsObj item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null)
            {
                setText(item.getGroupId() + " - " + item.getGroupName());
            }
        }
    }

    private List<ListGroupsObj> lisGroups;

    public static class ListGroupsObj
    {

        private int groupId;
        private String groupName;

        public static ListGroupsObj newInstance()
        {
            return new ListGroupsObj();
        }

        public ListGroupsObj()
        {
        }

        public ListGroupsObj groupId(int groupId)
        {
            this.groupId = groupId;
            return this;
        }

        public ListGroupsObj groupName(String groupName)
        {
            this.groupName = groupName;
            return this;
        }

        public int getGroupId()
        {
            return groupId;
        }

        public String getGroupName()
        {
            return groupName;
        }

        //        @Override
//        public String toString()
//        {
//            return serverName;
//        }
    }
}
```

How I can make the code more compact and easy for use?

Comment: What do you mean by "easy for use"? Are you planning on letting other people use this code as (part of) a library?

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I don't know much about JavaFX, but I do know Java so I can help you with the things I can come up with:

If by "more compact" you mean "less number of lines" there are several things that you can do:

- Use Java coding conventions and don't put `{` on a new line. That alone will save several lines.
- You have unnecessary empty lines on some places, for example in the beginning of methods.
- Remove commented code, such as your `toString` method (Also, including commented code in your question here will only make us confused - Do you want your commented code to be reviewed as well? - Rhetorical question, no need to answer that)
- Remove public empty constructors, those are added automatically by Java
- Instead of using anonymous inner classes, you can let your `Listobject` class implement the `ChangeListener<ListGroupsObj>` and `Callback<ListView<ListGroupsObj>, ListCell<ListGroupsObj>>` interfaces, this would let you use:

  ```
  listGroups.setCellFactory(this);
  ```

  and elsewhere in the `Listobject` class you put this method:

  ```
  @Override
  public ListCell<ListGroupsObj> call(ListView<ListGroupsObj> p) {
      return new GroupListCell();
  }
  ```

  if you use this approach, you might want to extract an interface for your `Listobject` class, since those methods will be a part of it's public API (although there's not much harm in letting them be a part of the class' public API, it might confuse users of your class).

A couple of other notes:

- Are you sure you want `GroupConverter` to be a **`public`** static class? You might want to set it to private.
- `GroupListCell` could be, and probably should be, a `private static class`
- Not really sure why you are using a factory method for the `ListGroupsObj` class. Instead you could pass `groupId` and `groupName` to the constructor and make the two fields **final** and you will have yourself a nice immutable class. Then you can remove your "setters" for this class.

Edit: Adding a sample of code to show how to implement `ChangeListener<ListGroupsObj>` and `Callback<ListView<ListGroupsObj>, ListCell<ListGroupsObj>>` on an existing class instead of using anonymous classes:

```
public class Listobject extends Application implements Callback<ListView<ListGroupsObj>, ListCell<ListGroupsObj>>, ChangeListener<ListGroupsObj> {

    @Override
    public ListCell<ListGroupsObj> call(ListView<ListGroupsObj> p) {
        return new GroupListCell();
    }
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ListGroupsObj> arg0, ListGroupsObj arg1, ListGroupsObj arg2) {
        if (arg2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Selected Group: " + arg2.getGroupId() + " - " + arg2.getGroupName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        ...

        listGroups.setConverter(new GroupConverter());
        listGroups.setButtonCell(new GroupListCell());
        listGroups.setCellFactory(this); // "this" means "the current Listobject"
        // the current Listobject is also a Callback<ListView<ListGroupsObj>, ListCell<ListGroupsObj>>, which is what the `setCellFactory` method wants

        listGroups.setEditable(true);

        listGroups.getItems().addAll(ob, osb, oa, oz);
        listGroups.setValue(ob);

        // Display the selected Group
        listGroups.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(this); // "this" is a Listobject, which is also a ChangeListener<ListGroupsObj>

        ...
    }
}
```